# Is there a way to debug memory leaks which happen outside v8 heap

Tags: node.js

I have a production application running on NodeJS which serves a decent amount of traffic. While things are smooth post deployment, the performance starts to degrade after few hours.

We noticed on newrelic that the non-heap memory of NodeJS continues to increase steadily while V8 heap is kind of consistent. We have tried using Chrome DevTools but couldn't find the issue. Are there any tools which will help me debug the memory leak happening outside V8 heap?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Gxg.png

Tried Google Chrome DevTools to find the leak but no luck.

Comment: Since you're specifically asking about non-V8-heap memory, this is not a "v8" question, is it?

Comment: I think its not related to v8..but posted an example image just to be double sure. We can drop v8 tag.

Comment: The issue was related to our cache library. Related to creating a lot of new connections instead of re-using them.