# Node.js non-heap memory leaks

Tags: node.js

The situation we're observing in New Relic is below.  With blue being non-heap memory, orange - V8 heap used, red - V8 heap free.

As you see, non-heap memory is steadily growing until the app crashes with out of memory.

Chrome Node.js DevTools seem to help only with V8 heap memory, which doesn't seem to be causing the issue here.

What's Node.js non-heap memory?  Does it include stack? What could be causing non-heap memory leaks?  And how do we diagnose them?

[image: Steadily growing Node.js non-heap memory]

Comment: here was same question, and it was bacause of many connections to cache, and not to reuse them. Maybe, this is the same issue in your app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616488/is-there-a-way-to-debug-memory-leaks-which-happen-outside-v8-heap

Comment: @michalpavlik I saw this question.  Not sure what cache they were referring to, but we don't cache any connections and don't use any cache library.  At least not beyond recommended settings of the modules we use. Also it's not clear to me how those connections wouldn't end up on the heap.